# How do i put a text on top of a marker and align it centered ?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to put a text on top of marker and align it  centered.For some reason i cant move it up more than in picture.Also its not centered.

```
<Marker.Animated

  ref={marker => { this.marker = marker; }}
  image={avatars[this.userData.avatar]}

  coordinate = {{
    latitude: this.state.playerLocation.latitude,
    longitude: this.state.playerLocation.longitude
}}      
title={this.userData.userName}
    >
    <View style={{justifyContent:'center',alignContent:'center'}}>
    <Text style={{textAlign:'center',color:'white',margionTop:-20}}>{this.userData.userName}</Text>

    </View>

    </Marker.Animated>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex:1`

```
<View style={{
             flex:1,
             justifyContent:'center',
             alignContent:'center',
           }}
        >
    <Text style={{
            flex:1,
            textAlign:'center',
            color:'white',
            margionTop:-20
        }}
    >{this.userData.userName}</Text>

</View>
```

Comment: this didnt change.I removed marker img property and added it as a child to marker and it worked.